# curl: request is missing authentication header - authentication header there

Tags: curl, vpn

to Add more context: I am trying to make a curl request to the Seamless.gov API. On a different computer the same curl command works. However, when I run the curl command on my machine it doesn't work.

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Date: 1530285602" -H "Authorization: HMAC-SHA256 api_key=XXXXXXXX nonce=12335 signature=XXXXXXXXXXXXX" -d 'false' https://nycopp.seamlessdocs.com/api/form/CO1708XXXXXXXXXXXXX/elements
```

I have the following version of `curl`:

```
curl: stable 7.60.0 (bottled), HEAD [keg-only] Get a file from an HTTP, HTTPS or FTP server https://curl.haxx.se/ /usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.60.0 (423 files, 3MB)   Poured from bottle on 2018-06-29 at 11:44:32 From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/curl.rb
==> Dependencies Build: pkg-config ✔ Optional: openssl ✘, rtmpdump ✘, libssh2 ✘, c-ares ✘, libmetalink ✘, nghttp2 ✘
==> Options
--with-c-ares   Build with C-Ares async DNS support
--with-gssapi   Build with GSSAPI/Kerberos authentication support.
--with-libmetalink  Build with libmetalink support.
--with-libssh2  Build with scp and sftp support
--with-nghttp2  Build with HTTP/2 support (requires OpenSSL)
--with-openssl  Build with OpenSSL instead of Secure Transport
--with-rtmpdump     Build with RTMP support
--HEAD  Install HEAD version
==> Caveats This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local, because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:   echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/curl/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/curl/include For pkg-config to find this software you may need to set:
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/curl/lib/pkgconfig
```

Same `curl` command works on another machine but not on mines, could it be an issue with the version or the operating system. I'm running on Mac OS High Sierra

```
 {
    "error": true,
    "error_log": [
        {
            "error_code": "missing_header",
            "error_message": "Request is missing header: `Authorization`",
            "error_description": "{\"Host\":\"XXXX.seamlessdocs.com\",\"Connection\":\"close\",\"X-Real-IP\":\"161.185.7.10\",\"X-Forwarded-For\":\"161.185.7.10\",\"X-Forwarded-Host\":\"nycopp.seamlessdocs.com\",\"X-Forwarded-Port\":\"443\",\"X-Forwarded-Proto\":\"https\",\"X-Original-URI\":\"\\\/api\\\/form\\\/CO1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\\/elements\",\"X-Scheme\":\"https\",\"Content-Length\":\"5\",\"user-agent\":\"curl\\\/7.54.0\",\"accept\":\"*\\\/*\",\"content-type\":\"application\\\/json\",\"date\":\"1530285602\",\"authorization\":\"HMAC-SHA256 api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX nonce=12335 signature=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX\"}"
        },
        {
```

Comment: Please enter the shell output as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: @mbuechmann done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one hint in the error message:

> ==> Caveats This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local, because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

OS X already has curl installed and this binary is used. This version does not work with your request. To find out where homebrew has installed curl execute:

```
ll /usr/local/opt/curl
```

You will get an output like that:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 maltebuchmann  admin    21B Jun 30 09:50 /usr/local/opt/curl -> ../Cellar/curl/7.60.0
```

With that info you can execute your above command:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.60.0/bin/curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Date: 1530285602" -H "Authorization: HMAC-SHA256 api_key=XXXXXXXX nonce=12335 signature=XXXXXXXXXXXXX" -d 'false' https://nycopp.seamlessdocs.com/api/form/CO1708XXXXXXXXXXXXX/elements
```

You can follow the printed instructions to add the installation folder to your path:

> If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:   echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

Or, you can forcefully link it with homebrew:

```
brew link curl --force
```

But do this at your own risk :)

Comment: can I delete the `curl` version installed thru brew and just have the one already installed with OS X?

Comment: OS X's curl version is causing the problems. The homebrew version fixes it and is just not accessible by default. The steps above fixes the accessibility.

Comment: So it works if I make the curl command using the steps above but what if I would like to set curl to default the version install via brew? I mean so I don't have to run `usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.60.0/bin/curl` everytime and just use `curl`

Comment: You can either add the path `/usr/local/opt/curl/bin` to your $PATH variable (see above) or try to link it with the `--force` option (see above). Former approach is recommended.